# How to add combinations values if rows don't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, is there a way to add rows which are not there (based on certain combinations).

All rows without values:

```
Col-a Col-a 
Col-a Col-b 
Col-a Col-c 
...
```

The database:

```
Col-a Col-a Val-a
Col-a Col-b Val-b
Col-b Col-a Val-c
Col-b Col-b Val-d
...
```

Suppose a row with *Col-a Col-c* doesn't exist in db, I want to add `Col-a, Col-c, 0` that is just insert the missing row with a zero value.

Example:

```
1,1,50
1,2,100
2,2,100
```

So here we are missing 2,1 hence add 2,1,0.
I shall give a set [1,2] where values should be present for both.

Expected output:

```
1,1,50
1,2,100
2,1,0
2,2,100
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Where did `Col-a Col-a `, `Col-a Col-b`, `Col-a Col-c` come from?

Comment: You could add a unique constraint to the two columns, and make the default value for the number 0.

Comment: What is missing,  is '123' missing?

Comment: @Reno They are just numbers like 1,2,3.. SO we could just put an increment there.. There data is actually generated else where.. I only want to add missing rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put in "union" them..

```
select '' col-a, '' col-b, '' col-c, [null your_table.fields] 
union 
select '' col-a, '' col-b, '' col-c, your_table.*
from your_table
```

***update after comments and the clearing in the original question:***

You could try this sql statement..

```
select THeaders.col_a, THeaders.col_b, TSrcValues.col_c
from
(
  select 1 as col_a, 1 as col_b, 0 as col_c from dual
  union
  select 1 as col_a, 2 as col_b, 0 as col_c from dual
  union
  select 1 as col_a, 3 as col_b, 0 as col_c from dual
  union
  select 2 as col_a, 1 as col_b, 0 as col_c from dual
  union
  select 2 as col_a, 2 as col_b, 0 as col_c from dual
  union
  select 2 as col_a, 3 as col_b, 0 as col_c from dual
)THeaders
left join
(
  select TSrc.*
  from 
  (
    select 
    case when YourValue = 100 then 1 else case when YourValue = 200 then 2 else case when YourValue = 300 then 3 else 0 end end end col_a,
    case when YourValue = 100 then 1 else case when YourValue = 200 then 2 else case when YourValue = 300 then 3 else 0 end end end col_b,
    YourValue as col_c 
    from YourTable 
  ) TSrc
  where TSrc.col_a <> 0 or TSrc.col_b <> 0
) TSrcValues
on THeaders.col_a = TSrcValues.col_a and THeaders.col_b= TSrcValues.col_b
;
```

you should personalize your ranges of values in the "case when" clauses

Comment: col-a,colb should just be picked from a set like [1,2,3] and combinations like (1,1) or (1,2) etc..

Comment: Do you need only of some table of col-a and  col-b like so: 1, 1 | 1, 2 | 1, 3 | 2, 1 | 2, 2 | 2, 3| ?

Comment: Yes, I wanted that.

Comment: thank you for your comment. May also confirm this answer like answer of election please? thanks again

Comment: I haven't check'd this but shall try.

Answer (score 0):

Your example needs more clarity. But if I understand you correctly, you need find all the unique values of of the first column and combine it with all unique values of the second column, and insert the row if that combination doesn't exist:

```
INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2, value)
SELECT a.col1, b.col2,0
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM foo) AS a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM foo) AS b
LEFT JOIN foo
  ON a.col1 = foo.col1
    AND b.col2 = foo.col2
WHERE foo.value IS NULL;
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee82b8/3) showing the SELECT component working

Comment: Not what I wanted, thanks anyway. I wanted 1,1|1,2|2,1|2,2.. like (1,1 or 1,2) if any of those rows are missing a value in the third column I just want it to be 0.